# Cannot delete entity, must delete login profile first

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Is possible to delete a user while using `AWS` Java sdk ? I have tried to delete a user and there is a error message

```
Cannot delete entity, must delete login profile first.
```

The relevant code snippet is:

```
AWSIam.deleteUser(new DeleteUserRequest().withUserName(user));
```

Comment: seems like you need to delete the login profile first. do that then the user.

Comment: Did you delete all items attached to the user? [DeleteUser documentation -  *"you must delete the items attached to the user manually, or the deletion fails."*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteUser.html)

Comment: Just tried deleting the user, after detaching all policies e.t.c. `DetachAll(user);`

Comment: @mavriksc I will try deleting the login profile and let you know.

Comment: @mavriksc deleting the login profile is the way to go. can you make your comment an answer so that i can accept it?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You need to delete the login profile first.

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer here from mavriksc simply states that you need to do exactly what the error message says ("delete the login profile"), but does not offer any clues as to how to do that.

If you need to just delete a user's login profile manually (not using the Java SDK), you can do so using the [AWS CLI `delete-login-profile` method](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/iam/delete-login-profile.html):

```
aws iam delete-login-profile --user-name=username
```

After doing that, the Java SDK `deleteUser()` method should succeed.

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  It seems like this is the kind of thing that would automatically happen if you tried to delete a user. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteLoginProfile.html

Answer (score 1):

I also saw the same error which in my case was resolved by detaching attached user policies. In my case it was in AWS console, but I think the same may be relevant for using Java SDK.

You can refer to [Working with IAM Policies section of AWS SDK for Java Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteUserPolicy.html) for more details on managing IAM policies using Java code.